# ASP.NET MVC: how to make all unspecified URLs direct to one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got an ASP.NET MVC app that's working nicely with a handful of controllers, e.g. "Home", "Services" and "Go".  The "Go" controller is where all the content is.

Now the marketing folks have come and said they don't want to see the word "go" in the URL.  In other words, instead of:

```
http://mydomain.com/go/geography/africa
```

they want to have:

```
http://mydomain.com/geography/africa
```

I cannot create a controller for every path that they might want... so is there any way of writing my routing in Global.asax.cs in such a way that requests to "services" and "home" will be treated the normal way, but anything else will implicitly be routed to the "go" controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, I worked it out myself, without URL rewriting!

Inside `RegisterRoutes()` in Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute("Services", "services/{action}/{*qualifier}",
  new { controller = "Services", action = "Index", qualifier = UrlParameter.Optional });
// and other controllers that I want to work the normal way
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*path}", 
  new { controller = "Go", action = "Index", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And in my `GoController` class

```
public ActionResult Index(string path) { ... }
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Are you on IIS7? It might be easiest to just implement URL rewriting on the server for this, rather than hacking about with your routes in `Global.asax.cs`.

**EDIT:** I've only ever done URL rewriting in Apache. For what it's worth that would be done using something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^go/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Have a look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/ and http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/. Hopefully they'll give you enough info to be able to get this working in IIS 7

Comment: +1 Ah, yes, that's not a bad idea.  Never done a URL rewrite though, can you please help me with what settings to use?

Comment: @Shaul Ok, I've added an example of how to do this in Apache (haven't any experience of using URL rewriting in IIS yet, but the regex should be pretty similar) with some links on doing this in IIS 7. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a mapping that does "`geography/{country}`" and have it specify the controller manually and add the country as a parameter. I've seen it done to prevent things like "`Dashboard/Dashboard`" etc.

An example can be seen at [Kazi Manzur Rashid's Blog - ASP.NET MVC Best Practices (Part 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx) #15 for what I am describing.

Comment: +1 It's a good idea, and it would probably work, but in my case the content is potentially going to be very dynamic and I don't want to change hard-coded mappings every time they come up with a new path off the root.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this: http://www.iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx ?

Comment: I found a solution myself, but +1 anyway for a cool and worthwhile link!

Answer (score 0):

you could try mapping a route of "`{action}/{id}`" with a default set for the controller. But that'll also match anything of the form "`{controller}/{action}`" too - unless you can do some clever constraining.